# Spring load velocity template from string

Tags: java, spring, templates, velocity

I'm currently using  `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString()` method to read velocity templates file to send emails. now I created an editor(something like ckeditor or cleditor) which I would like to allow users to create their own templates and save the template content into a string in database, so they can freely create their own email templates and use them.

but I can't find a equivalent way to `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString` which can load the template from a String. or maybe someone can suggest me the correct way to do this feature.

thanks

Spring: 4.06
velocity: 1.7
velocity tool: 2.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this with Spring's VelocityEngineUtils so you'll need to use Velocity directly.  Take a look at [VelocityEngine.evaluate](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/VelocityEngine.html#evaluate%28org.apache.velocity.context.Context,%20java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).  You can pass the template in as a String.  From the docs:

> renders the input string using the context into the output writer. To
>   be used when a template is dynamically constructed, or want to use
>   Velocity as a token replacer.

Comment: Thanks, I endup using directly Velocity and VelocityEngine.evaluate